# Slide a link to top on image hover

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to slide the plus icon link when the user hovers on the image. when the image isn't hovered I have placed the button outside of image and set the `opacity: 0`. then on hover I want it to slide in. so I'm setting the `opacity: 1` and changing its positions. but on hover the link don't show up.

Any suggestions?

```css
.project {
  position: relative;
}

.project .image {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.project .image::before {
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(100, 81, 246, 0.9);
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
}

.project .image img {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 51px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 51px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.project .image img:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 65px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 65px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.project .project:hover,
.project .image:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.project .project:hover .view-link,
.project .image:hover .view-link {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 40%;
}

.project .view-link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #fffefe;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.project .view-link:hover {
  color: #cacaca;
}
```

```html
<link
rel="stylesheet"
href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.0/css/all.css"
integrity="sha384-OLYO0LymqQ+uHXELyx93kblK5YIS3B2ZfLGBmsJaUyor7CpMTBsahDHByqSuWW+q"
crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<div class="project">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/590x390/000/fff&text=Some+Image" alt="" />
  </div>
  <a class="view-link" href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-3x"></i>
  </a>
  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Where can we test what you've done so far?

Comment: Let me add the css too

Comment: @AndyHoffman Updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
.project .project:hover .view-link
```

You're referencing `.project` twice but there is only one mention of it in your HTML.

It should be:

```
.project:hover .view-link
```

Also, there was some missing HTML in your example code of which your CSS depended. I added two divs for `#home-d` and `.projects-wrapper`, respectively.

**Demo**

```css
.project {
  position: relative;
}

.project .image {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.project .image::before {
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(100, 81, 246, 0.9);
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
}

.project .image img {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 51px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 51px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.project .image img:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 65px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 65px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.project .project:hover,
.project .image:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.project:hover .view-link,
.project .image:hover .view-link {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 40%;
}

.project .view-link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #fffefe;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.project .view-link:hover {
  color: #cacaca;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-OLYO0LymqQ+uHXELyx93kblK5YIS3B2ZfLGBmsJaUyor7CpMTBsahDHByqSuWW+q" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="project">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/590x390/000/fff&text=Some+Image" alt="" />
  </div>
  <a class="view-link" href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-3x"></i>
  </a>
  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
</div>
```